# Executable of “Open with” dialog on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How can I open the "Open with other application" dialog in Linux Ubuntu from terminal and other programs? Something like ./openwith myfile or explorer.exe --openwith-dialog myfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you search might be `mimeopen`.

A quasi similar thread can be found here https://askubuntu.com/questions/470022/show-open-with-dialogue-using-a-command
(Thanks to chaos)

You can also look at the command `xdg-mime`. A thread about its usage can be found here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060284/how-to-use-the-xdg-mime-command and https://askubuntu.com/questions/15354/how-to-open-file-with-default-application-from-command-line?rq=1)

Comment: Is there a way to show a graphical window for selecting a program for an open file instead of a dialog in the terminal

Comment: May be this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/470022/show-open-with-dialogue-using-a-command?

Comment: Unfortunately, it only tells about the console version.